# How to reorder a Sembast Store

Tags: list, flutter, sembast

I've created an App that allows Users to create their own workoutplans. Therefore I'm storing the exercises in a sembast store.

I wondered if and how it is possible to reorder the workout. I'm planning on using the ReordarableListView but I just don't understand on how to update the data in the Store. I think the best way would be to reorder the Exercises with their own sembastkey (int in my case). But I just don't know man hahaha.

Lets say I've dragged Exercise7 just above exercise3, would it be overkill to completely destroy and recreate the list for all exercises with ExerciseN (N >3)? That's the only way I can think of doing it but i hope there is a more efficient way. I would really be pleased if someone could give me a hint on how to solve this task more easily.
Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to sembast but indeed something that is not always easy to solve. Typically I would add a “sort” column which could be an int. Moving an item would mean updating the sort value

If we have items A, B and C with the given sort values

```
A 100
B 200
C 300
```

And want to move A between B and C then you could set A sort value to 250

```
B 200
A 250
C 300
```

This solution becomes more complex if there is no value between B and C as you would have to update both A and either B or C sort values

An easiest solution would be to store an additional singleton with a single list of all the keys i.e. `[A,B,C]` without changing your records and only updating this singleton when an item is moved.